# how to increment id automatically in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Iam working with mvc3, I have a form in that users fill out and then it gets e-mailed to me.I am trying to get an example of how I would create an ID (based on my own conventions) that I can use for different users based on that unique id.
my form contains several fileds like registration number(which is user created their own),name,country,and some other details.

This is the convention I am striving for:

[CountryCode]-[Registration number]-[Continuous Numbers]..
How can i generate this Unique id in MVC3. Iam using following code...
Here i want to increment value of num

```
public string code(Model model,string Uniquecode)
    {
        var num = 100;
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", model.Country, model.VehRegistrationNo,num);
        }

    }
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get last used id an add 1.

Comment: I will suggest you to use `GUID`